# ActiveMQ Artemis HA cluster using shared storage on Windows

Tags: windows, activemq-artemis

I have already configured ActiveMQ Artemis HA cluster on Linux using shared storage through NFSv4. I am trying to set it up on Windows as well.

However, I could not get the shared storage to work properly. There was always an issue with the slave node accessing the shared files (e.g. file locking). I have tried sharing the storage using Samba and NFSv3 client (Windows does not support NFSv4 client), but neither did work. When I ran both master and slave on a single Windows host, the cluster was initialized and worked as expected.

Is it possible to set up a cluster on Windows using shared storage or do I need to use another policy, like data replication instead?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom line is that you need to use a remote file-system that supports file locking. To my knowledge Samba and NFSv3 *do not* support file locking as necessary whereas NFSv4 *does*. If Windows, for whatever reason, can't use NFSv4 then you'll need to use some other remote file system that supports file locking or ditch shared store for replication or potentially even JDBC. Of course, ditching Windows also an option.